# Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginBean' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I get the following error whenever I use the Spring form tag library in my index.jsp file. Form works fine if I use HTML markup instead. I'm using Eclipse Kepler, Spring 4.1.1 Release, and Tomcat 7. Previous questions pointed to the need to bind an object model to the .jsp page, which I believe I have done in the controller. Previous questions also pointed out errors in naming conventions, which I believe are not an issue in this case.  Any thoughts?

Here is the stacktrace:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/TrackRecord] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginBean' available as request attribute] with root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginBean' available as request attribute
>   At org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:144)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)

LoginBean.java

```java
public class LoginBean {

/**
 * default constructor
 */
public LoginBean() {

}
/**
 * constructor
 * @param username
 * @param password
 */
public LoginBean(String username, String password){

}

@Size(min=1, message= "username is required.")
private String username;

@Size(min=1, message= "password is required.")
private String password;

public boolean validate() {
    if (username == null || username.equals("")) {
        return false;
    }

    if (password == null || password.equals("")) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

LoginController.java

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelAndView model) {
        model.addObject("loginBean", new LoginBean());
        System.out.println("LoginBean created!");
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addlogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addLogin(@ModelAttribute("loginBean") @Valid LoginBean login, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        EmployeeBean employee = (new LoginManager()).authenticate(ILoginService.NAME, login);
        System.out.println("Controller employee = " +  employee);

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "loginerror";
        }

        if (employee.getID() == 0) {
            return "loginerror";
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
            return "home";
        }
    }
}
```

Login.jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"  %>
<%@ taglib prefix="myTags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <h3>Welcome, Enter Login</h3>

<form:form method="POST" action="addlogin" modelAttribute="loginBean">

Username
<form:input path="username" cssClass="input"/>
<form:errors path="username" cssClass="error"/>
Password
<form:input path="password" cssClass="input"/>
<form:errors path="password" cssClass="error"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
</form:form>

</body>

</html>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">


<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- the application context definition for the spring DispatcherServlet -->

<context:component-scan base-package="springcontroller" /> 

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/> 

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <!-- Configures Spring MVC DataBinder instances -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
               <property name="validator" ref="validator" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Creates the JSR-303 Validator -->
<bean id="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

</beans>
```

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

<display-name>TrackRecord web app</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filters.LoginTrackingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/addlogin</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>IAddVinylService</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>dao.jdbc.AddVinylServiceJDBCImpl</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>

<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>ILoginService</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>dao.jdbc.LoginServiceJDBCImpl</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>

<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>ISearchVinylService</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>dao.jdbc.SearchVinylServiceJDBCImpl</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>

<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>IDeleteVinylService</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>dao.jdbc.DeleteVinylServiceJDBCImpl</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>

<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>ApplicationPropertiesXML</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>ApplicationProperties.xml</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>

<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>ApplicationPropertiesXSD</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>ApplicationProperties.XSD</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>

<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/aaa</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

Comment: How do you access the form in `login.jsp`? What is the original HTTP request?

Comment: Look at the stack trace. The error is being thrown from the page `/TrackRecord`. Are you binding a `loginBean` to the model attribute there?